# can't use modules for python on macos

Tags: python, macos

I installed py2exe (but happens almost with every module) using `pip3 install py2exe` and it goes well. If I try to use the module in VSC, it says "module not found". How can I solve this? Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the rigth python?

Comment: The selected interpreter in Visual Studio is not the one that `pip3` belongs to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I selected the right python :(

Comment: [According to its PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/), py2exe (sensibly) requires Windows.